# Meaning of the expression "to be round at somewhere"

Tags: expressions

> It was an ordinary Thursday evening in January - at least I thought so. **I was round at my girlfriend Mel's flat** and it was to her that I'd aimed my question, as for some unknown reason she'd just turned off the TV even though I'd quite clearly been watching it.

I cannot get the meaning of the phrase in bold. Can you help me please? If someone is watching TV, how can they be round at somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This usage of [optional] adverbial ***round*** is covered by [oxforddictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/round)...

> **round** ADVERB
>    **4** So as to reach a new place or position, typically by moving to the other side of something:
>    *He made his way **round** to the back of the building*
>    *They went the long way **round** by the main road*
>    ...
>    **4.2** INFORMAL Used to convey the idea of visiting someone else:
>    *Why don’t you come **round** to my flat?*

The implications of including ***round*** in OP's example include the fact that although the speaker doesn't live *permanently* at his girlfriend's flat, it's not uncommon for him to be there (you wouldn't normally say you'd *"I was round [somewhere] last night"* if that was the only time you'd ever been there).

It's also unlikely you'd include ***round*** for some place that was *a long way away* (probably influenced by *round/around = **nearby***).

---

There might be some debate as to whether OP's example is *prepositional* or *adverbial*. I don't see that distinction as useful here, but it may help to note that ***at, round*** and **round at** are all grammatically valid.

Essentially, you're ***round*** [at] some place ***round, around, near, nearby*** wherever you normally live (often, some place you regularly spend time at).